# DataGridView solo numeros

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo un datagridview con varias columas pero quiero que solo en 3 columnas se pueda escribir solo numeros y en las demas queden normal

Este es el codigo que tengo pero coge todas las filas y no las que quiero

```
 private void tblarticulo_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tblarticulo.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0 | tblarticulo.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1 | tblarticulo.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl dText = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)e.Control;
            dText.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Control_KeyPress);
            dText.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Control_KeyPress);
        }
    }
    private void Control_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no estabas eliminando el manejador `Control_KeyPress` en caso de que la columna no fuera una de las que querías controlar, lo que hacía que en cuanto entrabas en una columna *a filtrar*, a partir de ese momento todas las columnas llamaban al `Control_KeyPress`.

La solución mas sencilla es eliminar el manejador siempre que se lance el evento `EditingControlShowing`:

```
private void tblarticulo_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    dText.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Control_KeyPress);
    if (tblarticulo.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0 | tblarticulo.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1 | tblarticulo.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl dText = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)e.Control;
        dText.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Control_KeyPress);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes indicar que columnas son las que va a capturar números...

```
private void tblarticulo_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)    
{
String cNombreCelda =  dataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name; 
   If (sCellName == "LACELDA") 
    {

     e.Control.KeyPress  += new EventHandler(CheckKey);

   }
  }
```

Y el evento realizar la comparación de los caracteres...

```
private void CheckKey(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
 if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) 
    && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) 
    && e.KeyChar != '.')
 {
    e.Handled = true;
 }   
 }
```